# Deleting selected row except first row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet with one command button to add a new row and another command button to delete the selected row. The code I am using in command button for deleting row is below. This code deletes one selected row:-

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxxx"
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
ActiveSheet.Protect "xxxx", True, True
```

But how to make sure that the First Row (Row K12 in my case) is never deleted because this row has all formulas and formatting.
Also how to delete multiple rows. 
Much appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap in:

```
If ActiveCell.Row > 12 Then
...
End If
```

I am guessing that you won't want to be deleting any rows above K12 either.

Comment: But how is it possible to delete multiple rows, if I select and highlight more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one for you. Here you selsct multiple cells

```
Sub test()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxxx"
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Application.InputBox("select you range (use ctrl to Select non adjacen cells):", "multiple rows to delete", ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If ActiveCell.Row > 12 Then
 rng.EntireRow.Delete
Else
MsgBox "do not select from row 12 or above"
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect"xxxx", True,True
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, but I am trying to do something bit different. I want to select some rows by highlighting them manually by mouse drag and click the command button to delete the selected rows. My earlier code works for only one row and not for multiple selection of rows manually.

Comment: @VinzB you could change the line `set rng = ...` replace whats after `=` to `Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                           RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)` Have not tested this tho

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. So I am still using the code as below. However with this code I am still unable to select multiple rows using mouse drag and click on command button to delete selected rows:-
    If ActiveCell.Row > 12 Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxxx"
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
    ActiveSheet.Protect "xxxx", True, True
    Endif